# javax CriteriaBuilder attribute equal on specific position

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, criteria, criteriaquery

I am using javax CriteriaBuilder with CriteriaQuery like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = getSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<MyClazz> criteria = builder.createQuery(MyClazz.class);
Root<MyClazz> root = criteria.from(MyClazz.class);
Predicate predicate = builder.and(
                            builder.equal( root.get("attribute1"), "somestring");
                    );
criteria.select(root).where(predicate);
Query<MyClazz> query = getSession().createQuery(criteria);
```

The thing is that "attribute1" has length ~20. I dont want to compare full attribute1 length, i just want records WHERE attribute1 on position [5,16]  equals "somsetring". Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You can prefer like for that case.

Comment: In `SQL` there is `SUBSTRING(attribute1, 5, 16) = "somestring"`

Comment: I think something like this `builder.equal(critBuilder.substring(root.get("attribute1"), 5, 16), "somestring");`

Comment: kunlun's answer is  the right one, thank you